# How to avoid line continuations in Python imports

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-2.5

I have a number of classes / functions to import from a module and linters/ style checkers (`pylint`, `flake`, `pep8`) are complaining that the line is too long and I am forced to use line continuation which is ugly:

```
from my_lengthy_module import FirstClass, SecondClass, ThirdClass, \  
foo_bar_with_long_name, bar_foo_with_longer_name, \
FourthClass, bar_foo_with_longer_name, foo_bar_with_longest_name
```

How to do it better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Python 2.5](https://docs.python.org/2.4/whatsnew/node10.html) introduced a concept of multi-line imports ([PEP-328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/)) which address this problem by extending the syntax of the import statement to include the imported names in brackets and thus avoiding line continuations:

```
from my_lengthy_module import (
    FirstClass, SecondClass, ThirdClass, 
    foo_bar_with_long_name, bar_foo_with_longer_name,
    FourthClass, bar_foo_with_longer_name, foo_bar_with_longest_name
)
```

Comment: This is correct. It is mentioned there that the implementation of this feature first appeared in Python 2.5.